# Detect whether user has clicked on empty rows in tableview

Tags: javafx, tableview, mouseevent, selectionmodel

I have a table view which has some rows. I am able to get the selected index which user has selected. I want to clear the selection when the user clicks on empty rows. How can I detect whether the user has clicked on empty rows or not?

I have tried below things.

```
cSVTableView.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new   EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {  
        public void handle(MouseEvent e) {    
            //int selectedIndex =     cSVTableView.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().get();  
            if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY && selectedIndex !=   -1 && selectedIndex <= modelList.size() - 1) {  
                contextMenu.show(cSVTableView, e.getScreenX(),   e.getScreenY());  
            } else if(e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY &&   selectedIndex==-1){  
                cSVTableView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();  
                contextMenu.hide();  
            } else {  
                contextMenu.hide();  
            }  
        }  
    });
```

I have tried this as well but it is not working

```
    tableView.setRowFactory(new Callback<TableView<MainModel>, TableRow<MainModel>>() {

        public TableRow<MainModel> call(TableView<MainModel> param) {
            final TableRow<MainModel> row = new TableRow<MainModel>();
            row.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<Event>() {

                public void handle(Event event) {
                    if((! row.isEmpty()) && ( ((MouseEvent) event).getButton()==MouseButton.PRIMARY)){
                        MainModel clickedRow = row.getItem();
                        System.out.println("clickedRow::" +clickedRow);
                    }

                }
            });
            return row;
        }
});
```

Comment: No that thing is different I am not getting the table row.

Comment: As sillyfly indicate, If you have the properties of this row, you can find out if it is empty !

Comment: The point is that to know if a row is empty, you *have to* get the reference to the table row, which you do using the row factory.

Comment: @James_D , I have tried it as well and updated my question with new code. Could you please help here?

Comment: I have tried the same code as suggested by sillyfly but it is not working. Any help would be appreciated.